# angular2 reuse formular component in another one

Tags: angular

With formbuilder I create 2  component of form, one  other

What I need is in   template use  and merge it to the parentForm formBuilder how can I achieve this ?

So my pseudo code is something like this

```
component:childForm
template: <inputA> <inputB>
class: formbuilder.group(inputA+inputB)
```

and now in my  I need reuse this  in my tempalte like this:

```
component:parentForm
template: <childForm> <inputC> <inputD>
class: formbuilder.group(inputC+inputD+new group.childForm)
```

Like this I don't need recreate in my   inputA and inputB because my  is already here and now I can check validity of my parentForm.valid  to check all input ?

I just donno how achieve this? any real example? with real code  onyl with one  please ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```ts
  private inheritControls(target: FormGroup, source: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(source.controls)
      .map(name => target.addControl(name, source.controls[name]));
  }
```

with:

```ts
  @ViewChild(FormGeneralComponent) general: any;
  @ViewChild(FormDatabaseComponent) database: any;
  @ViewChild(FormUsersComponent) users: any;

    this.inheritControls(this.setupForm, this.general.generalForm);
    this.inheritControls(this.setupForm, this.database.databaseForm);
    this.inheritControls(this.setupForm, this.users.usersForm);
```

Might be a little "dirty" but it works...

Comment: thanks, yes litle bit dirty, if someone have better way please let me know what is the best way to do this